# URL not appearing correctly in browser address bar

Tags: php, url, seo, e-commerce, prestashop

Using **Prestashop** for an e-commerce website

i have three categories

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Categories  |   Products                                    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Clothes     |   Image 1         Image 2         Image 3     |                                   
|   Mobile      |   Image 4         Image 5         Image 6     |
|   Cars        |   Image 7         Image 8         Image 1     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

when i **HOVER/CLICKED** over **CATEGORIES** the link generated by browser at the bottom of browser window in firefox is like this

```
www.website.com/Clothes-1
www.website.com/Mobiles-4
www.website.com/Cars-13
```

i selected **Mobile Category**, and link in the browser address bar is this

Address Bar (Browser ) `www.website.com/Mobiles-4`

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Categories              |   Products (Mobile)                       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Clothes                 |   Mobile 1    Mobile 2    Mobile 3        |                                   
|   Mobile (selected)       |   Mobile 4    Mobile 5    Mobile 6        |
|   Cars                    |   Mobile 7    Mobile 8    Mobile 1        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now when **HOVER/CLICKED** over any of the mobile available in Products it generate following url

`www.website.com/Mobiles/Mobile-4-34.html` **( Current behaviour )**

where as i feel it should generate url like this

`www.website.com/Mobiles-4/Mobile-4-34.html` <----------- **( Required is *Mobile-4*( i.e 4 is id) )**

> Current behaviour which also **creating SEO problems** ... i have
>   tried to change settings in preferences but it does nt work at all..
>   also i feel  prestashop framework is rewriting the url ... and i tried
>   to programmatically update the code by prestashop framework is
>   malfunctioning.

If some guideance or help by any fella?

Comment: :( no one to help .. with so much self work, detail and explanation

Answer (score 1):

### Prestashop standard

The default way Prestashop displays the friendly url is:

Product route: `/category/id-product-name.html`

Category route: `/id-category`

The diference between your example and the default PS 1.5 friendly-url behaviour is that in your example the *id* is not at the end of the product-name.

### Solution

Go to `Back Office->Preferences->SEO&URLs->Schema of URLs (page section)`

In the `Route to products` field you should have: `{category:/}{id}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html`

If I understand correctly your need you should have: `{id}-{category:/}{id}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html`

*Note:*

The `{id}` part of the rewritten URL is mandatory, so you can not get read of it by changing the back-office settings.

The only way you can do that is by making/purchasing a module for that. I recommend *Pretty URL*.

Comment: {id}-{category:/}{id}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html ... i tried this but id is same in category and product.. whereas id - category should be the id of category and id - rewirte ean should b of product... any idea how can we achieve separate ids

Comment: regardless of solution ... just wanna thanks for taking out the time and answering ... it would b great if u can resolve it ... thankx

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop SEO-friendly URLs are generated by the .htaccess file. Try to open your .htaccess and see how the URL rewriting is handled (you can operate manually on the parameters to fix it).

Alternatively, try to [regenerate your .htaccess](http://mypresta.eu/en/art/basic-tutorials/how-to-regenerate-htaccess-in-prestashop-1-5.html).